# Python: Subtracting from only one column in a list based on another condition

Tags: python

So I have a code that imports a .txt file and organizes its columns into a list using line.split()

basically in the form 
list1 = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)

the last value in list1 is a new list I created by

```
total = list1[1]+list1[2]+list1[3]+list1[4]+list1[5]
Info = []
    if total > 650:
        info.append(1.0)
    if total < 650:
        info.append(2.0)
```

I then added that to the end of list1

So printing list1 gives me

('031', '97', '108', '113', '48', '217', '14', [2.0])

('032', '97', '124', '147', '45', '355', '15', [1.0])

('033', '140', '145', '175', '50', '446', '14', [1.0])

('034', '133', '123', '115', '46', '430', '15', [1.0])

('035', '107', '92', '136', '45', '278', '13', [1.0])

('036', '98', '115', '130', '37', '387', '15', [1.0])

('037', '117', '69', '131', '34', '238', '12', [2.0])

('038', '134', '125', '132', '50', '434', '15', [1.0])

('039', '125', '116', '178', '50', '433', '15', [1.0])

('040', '125', '142', '156', '50', '363', '15', [1.0])

('041', '77', '51', '68', '45', '219', '15', [2.0])

('042', '122', '142', '182', '50', '447', '15', [1.0])

('043', '103', '123', '102', '46', '320', '15', [1.0])

('044', '106', '100', '127', '50', '362', '15', [1.0])

('045', '125', '110', '140', '50', '396', '15', [1.0])

('046', '120', '98', '129', '48', '325', '13', [1.0])

('047', '89', '70', '80', '46', '302', '14', [2.0])

('048', '99', '130', '103', '50', '436', '15', [1.0])

('049', '100', '87', '148', '17', '408', '13', [1.0])

('050', '104', '47', '91', '37', '50', '9', [2.0])

what I want to know is how to write a line of code that would subtract .5 from line1[7] when line1[6] = 13, subtract 1 when its 12, and subtract 1.5 when its 11 or lower

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can't subtract a number from a list, which is what `line1[7]` is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`line1[7]` is a list, so I'm assuming that you want to subtract from the number in the list. Something like this should do the job:

```
x = line1[6]

if x <= 11:
    line1[7][0] -= 1.5
elif x == 12:
    line1[7][0] -= 1
elif x == 13:
    line1[7][0] -= 0.5
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this? en, one line code

`line1[7][0] -= 1.5 if line1[6]<=11 else 0.5*(14-line1[6]) if line1[6]<=13 else 0`

Answer (score 0):

```
def convert_row(row):
    row[7][0] -= sorted([0.5,1.5,7-int(row[6])/2])[1]

list1 = [('031', '97', '108', '113', '48', '217', '14', [2.0]),
        ('032', '97', '124', '147', '45', '355', '15', [1.0])]
for x in list1:
     convert_row(x)
```

Seeing you wanted it on "a line of code", I kept it short and without if elif else. Basically I calculate 7-int(row[6])/2 which matches your cases (11 12 and 13), and then take the middle of that number, 0.5 and 1.5 to match every other case.